# Search in XML with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, search

trying to add a Ajax search function to a xml file, and found this exemple :

```
    <?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("my_xml_file.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('links');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

This works perfect but the xml I have to search is a bit different and I don't know how to setup the function according to my needs.
This is how is formatted my xml :

```
<data name="my_name"><![CDATA[Data content]]></data>
```

I changed

```
`$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('links'); to $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('data');`
```

But how to change

```
 $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

to have 
`$y=$x->item($i)-> name;` and `$z=$x->item($i)->Data` content without CDATA ?;

Thanx a lot for your help !!!

Comment: please can you post us a sample of the xml file you're trying to search?

Comment: Personally, I'd ditch the DOM functions, which I always find far too wordy, and use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml). There are some nice examples in the manual of how to use it, just bear in mind *print_r and var_dump don't work well with it*. Getting string content or CDATA in SimpleXML works the same way: `$content = (string)$element`

Comment: i posted a solution for ur problem, however, i agree with @IMSoP

Answer (score 0):

add this in your loop:

```
 $attr = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('name');
if($attr==""){
continue;
}
//take care of the $attr

echo $attr;
```